# Handle AJAX request to PHP url for JSON data. I cant pass the data

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Im trying to pass my data from mySQL database to returnData.PHP to an AJAX request as JSON data to javascript in a .js file.  So far I can retrieve my data from a mysql query and encode it into json just fine.  Following is returnData.php

```
<?php
  include('../sqlFunctions/sqlFunctions.php');

//Establish connection to database
  $link = linkDB();

//set up a MySQL query
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM shelters;";

  if(!$results = $link->query($sql)){
    die("Query Unsuccessful");
  }

  $rows = array();

  while ($data = $results->fetch_assoc()) {
    $rows[] = $data;
  }
  $JSONRows = json_encode($rows);
  return $JSONRows;
?>
```

I call this page from a javascript function using AJAX and need to hand off this data.

```
  <script type="text/javascript">

    function getData(){
      var dataXMLhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
      dataXMLhttp.open("GET", "./js/returnData.php", true);
      dataXMLhttp.send();
      if(dataXMLhttp.readyState == 4 && dataXMLhttp.status == 200){
        var XMLdataResult = dataXMLhttp.responseText;
        window.alert("XMLdataResult Contains something.");
      }else{
        window.alert("404");
      }
    }getData();
</script>
```

I am recieving the 404  message.  Apparently my AJAX request is broken.  The return $JSONow obviously shows my noobness.  I have looked and read about AJAX intereacting with PHP, but can't see the pieces of the puzzle I am missing.

What is wrong with my AJAX request?
How can I get my JSON into a javascript variable for PARSing?

Thanks for reading.

Comment: Instead of return $JSONRows echo the $JSONRows. Oh its not $JSONRows its just $Rows

Comment: Sorry that was a typo on this end, I did actually json.encode into $JSONRows

Comment: could echo $JSONRows helps you?

Comment: 404 message it means there is issue in your ajax url. check it once

Comment: I mean echo $JSONRows definitly works to print out my JSON while I directly url to returnData.php.  But My ajax request is still 404.

Comment: Desel yea I just double check my path.  The 404 is my own troubleshooting message to show that

if(dataXMLhttp.readyState == 4 && dataXMLhttp.status == 200){

failed

Comment: the issue is that `"./js/returnData.php"` is most likely not the right relative path - the path is relative to the page's location - without knowing the relative "positions" of the page that calls the php and the php it's calling, that's the best I can do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ajax function is missing `onreadystatechange` event handler so it is always going to trigger the `alert('404')` - also the order of the commands within the function is generally out of order. The callback should typically be declared before opening the connection and sending the request.

Also pointed out was the use of a relative path - it would be easier to use an absolute path at all times,

```
function getData(){
    try{
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.onreadystatechange=function(){
            if( xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200 ){
                var data = this.response;
                alert( data );
            }
        }                               
        xhr.open( 'GET', '/js/returnData.php', true );
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
        xhr.send();

    }catch( err ){
        alert( err );
    }
}

getData.call( this );
```